# how to call list of array that has a child in javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array

i'm having a trouble on how to list array children using javascript.
here's my code in php:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($categories as $key => $cat) {
    if($cat['parent_id'] == 0){
    $arr[$cat['id']] = $cat;

    }else{
        $arr[$cat['parent_id']][] = $cat;
    }
}
```

Output of this is:

```
Array ( 
[1] => Array (
     [id] => 1
      [parent_id] => 0
      [name] => A 
        [0] => Array (
             [id] => 2 
             [parent_id] => 1
              [name] => B 
        ) 
        [1] => Array (
            [id] => 3
            [parent_id] => 1 
            [name] => C 
         ) 
        [2] => Array (
             [id] => 4 
             [parent_id] => 1
             [name] => D
        )
 ) 
 [5] => Array (
         [id] => 5
         [parent_id] => 0
         [name] => E
            [0] => Array (
               [id] => 6
               [parent_id] => 5
               [name] => F
             ) 
             [1] => Array (
                 [id] => 7
                 [parent_id] => 5
                 [name] => G
        )
)
```

here is the output that i wish to create using javascript or php:
[image: array chart]

Comment: What is wrong in your current output?

Comment: @SibirajPR i dont know how to display them like the image below my post.

Comment: One more problem is that when the child array has also a child array, it will not display it because my loop is    
 if($cat['parent_id'] == 0){
    $arr[$cat['id']] = $cat;

    } currently im only checking parent_id that is equal to 0, and still looking for solution how to modify it.. i hope someone could help.. :(

Comment: Better print the `print_r($categories)` structure here.

Comment: @SibirajPR here is the $categories:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [parent_id] => 0 [name] => A ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 5 [parent_id] => 0 [name] => E ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [parent_id] => 1 [name] => B ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 3 [parent_id] => 1 [name] => C ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 4 [parent_id] => 1 [name] => D ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 6 [parent_id] => 5 [name] => F ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 7 [parent_id] => 5 [name] => G ) )

Comment: you need a graphing/charting library.. check out google charts

Comment: try `$arr[$cat['parent_id']]['children'][] = $cat;` and check.

Comment: @SibirajPR here is the result:
Array ( [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [parent_id] => 0 [name] => A [children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [parent_id] => 1 [name] => B ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [parent_id] => 1 [name] => C ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 4 [parent_id] => 1 [name] => D ) ) ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 5 [parent_id] => 0 [name] => E [children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 [parent_id] => 5 [name] => F ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 7 [parent_id] => 5 [name] => G ) ) ) )

Comment: One more problem is that when the child array has also a child array, it will not display it because my loop is if($cat['parent_id'] == 0){ $arr[$cat['id']] = $cat; } currently im only checking parent_id that is equal to 0, and still looking for solution how to modify it.. i hope someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```html
print_r($cat[1][name]);
```

what does the result?

Comment: but i used to print_r ($arr[1][name]); and displays "A"

Answer (score 0):

```
$paren_arr = array("id"=>0, "children"=>array()); // Top parent category:
foreach ($arr as $key=>$child ) {
    /*If parent of current array is TOP (parent_id==0) 
        Add to TOP parent array. (TOP['children'][] = current array)
      Else
        Walk through each children of TOP parent. (parent_id!=0)
        If child of TOP parent's ID is Parent id of current array
            Add to TOP parent->child, this array. (TOP['children']['CHILD_ID'][] = current)
    */
    if ( !is_array($param) )
        continue;

    if ( $param['parent_id']==0 ) {
        $paren_arr['children'][$param['name']] = $param;
    } else {
        foreach ( $paren_arr['children'] as $name=>$child_param ) {
            if ( $param['parent_id']==$child_param['id'] ) {
                $paren_arr['children'][$name]['children'][$param['name']] = $param;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function can be optimized (with recursion) to work with different nested levels.